# NextJS 10 with Material UI compiling too slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, compilation, next.js

I have a project with many components, but event if I work on isolated components when I save the file and NextJS compile it takes too long. My develop time is affected by this issue.

I run 4 GB of RAM, but it is still slow

```
cross-env NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096" next
```

How can I solve this issue ?

What are the possible problems ?

Comment: Do you know specifically what's causing the long compile times? What does your build size look like?

Comment: I have many components, maybe because of this ?

Answer (score 7):

If you import components using

```
import {List,Grid,ListItem} from '@material-ui/core';
```

instead try use

```
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Gridfrom '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
```

that's worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this approach!